# Entering data from form into database: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, flask-sqlalchemy

Please ignore my hack job, I'm just trying to get data from a form inserted into SQL Server.

```
@app.route("/contact", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
   form = PayRoll_Form()

   if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.validate() == False:
           flash('All fields are required.')
           return render_template('contact.html', form = form)
       else:
           N = engine.execute(PayRoll.insert(),
               Name = request.form['Name'],
               CreateUserPK = request.form['CreateUserPK'],
               PeriodStart = request.form['PeriodStart'],
               PeriodStop = request.form['PeriodStop'],
               DueDate = request.form['DueDate'])
           session.add(N)
           session.commit()
           flash('Submited')
           return redirect("/contact")
   if request.method == 'GET':
       return render_template('contact.html', form = form)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing possible implementations here; the line `N = engine.execute(...` actually executes the `INSERT` against the DB directly. Trying to add the result to the current session and commit that session doesn't make sense. You would only use those methods if you had an ORM object that you made changes to (or created) and wanted to have committed, but you've already done this in the line referenced above.

Comment: Hmm ok, so are you saying I should take out the `N = engine.execute(...`?

Comment: @Everett no, the add and commit lines

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue here:

```
@app.route("/contact", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
   form = PayRoll_Form()

   if request.method == 'POST':
       if form.validate() == False:
           flash('All fields are required.')
           return render_template('contact.html', form = form)
       else:
           ins = PayRoll.insert().values(
               Name = request.form['Name'],
               CreateUserPK = request.form['CreateUserPK'],
               PeriodStart = request.form['PeriodStart'],
               PeriodStop = request.form['PeriodStop'],
               DueDate = request.form['DueDate'])
           result = connection.execute(ins)
           flash('Submited')
           return redirect("/contact")
   if request.method == 'GET':
       return render_template('contact.html', form = form)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```